# Error "The property 'JobHistory.Id' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'" after upgrading to EF Core 7

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

After upgrading to EF Core 7.0, when I attempt to do a batch insert, I get the following error message

> The property 'JobHistory.Id' has a temporary value while attempting to change the entity's state to 'Unchanged'. Either set a permanent value explicitly, or ensure that the database is configured to generate values for this property.

Here is the code that is run:

```
_context.JobHistories.ExecuteDelete();
_context.SaveChanges();
//_context.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("DELETE FROM dbo.JobHistories;");
_context.JobHistories.AddRange(jobHistories);
_context.SaveChanges();
```

I tried adding the following lines because EF Core 7.0 added bulk deletes, but nothing changed. I tried with and without the following lines.

```
_context.JobHistories.ExecuteDelete();
_context.SaveChanges();
```

jobHistories is a list of JobHistry that has several thousand objects all with an id of 0.

Here is the JobHistory Object

```
public class JobHistory
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public string BargeName { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime ArriveTime { get; set; }
        public DateTime DepartTime { get; set; }

        [Column(TypeName = "decimal(8,2)")]
        public decimal HoursWorked { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: How do you get  `jobHistories`?